# How to extend default React Native webpack config?

Tags: react-native, webpack

I would like to add aliases to my React Native project started from the scratch with default `react-native cli` tools.
I created a `webpack.config.js` in the app root folder hoping that this will be enough for webpack to catch in on the fly. But its never happened. 

Are any workarounds available?
**Currently my webpack.config.js  looks like that:**

```
var path = require('path');

const alias = {
  '~': __dirname,
  'assets': path.resolve('./app/assets/'),
  'native-styles': path.resolve('./app/native/styles')
}

module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    alias: alias,
  }
}
```

Comment: I think webpack now becomes irrelevant because React Native uses its own packager/bundler.